# Python: for loops and xrange()

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, repeat

I am learning Python and I came across something with the `for` loop.

Let's say I have a program that asks for 5 numbers. (I know it's pointless but it's good for an example.) Anyways, if I do this, it won't restart its cycle:

```
myNumbers = []
for x in xrange(5):
    try:
        myNumbers.append( int(raw_input()) )
    except ValueError:
        myNumbers = []
        x = -1
```

I thought if I had reset `x` to `-1` it would just make the `for` loop go on even more, but it never restarted. It still **only** went **5** times. The reason why I put `-1` there is because `x` would count back up to `0` right after that. I tried to find solutions, but there weren't any. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Any assignment to `x` inside the loop will be overwritten when you reach the end of the block, as it then takes the next value from `xrange`. Do you want a `while` loop instead?

Comment: Hold on; let me update my question.

Comment: Why converting the output of `raw_input()` (actually a string) to string? Why catching `ValueError`?

Comment: That was a mistype. There fixed it.

Comment: I was going to suggest while len(myNumbers)<5: try ... except pass

Answer (score 2):

`xrange()` (or `range()` ) are called generator functions, x is like the `local variable` that the for loop assigns the next value in the loop to.

`xrange()` returns the values in the range given in parameters 1 by 1 , and for loop assigns that to the variable x. So even if you change the value of x within the loop, xrange() has no idea about such a change and would still provide the next value in the range.

Example of generator functions -

```
def myrange(a):
    i = 0
    while i < a:
        yield i
        i = i + 1

>>> for x in  myrange(10):
...     print(x)
...     x = 1
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The value change in `x` is never propagated back to the `range()` or `xrange()` function.